# Ошибка с работы jPlayer в Opera и Sofari

Tags: jquery, opera, javascript, safari

Доброй ночи! Проблема с плеером jPlayer. Есть сайт: http://barracudasound.com. Проигрывание музыки с хрома, мозиллы, ie работает вроде нормально, а вот в Opera и Safari непонятные вещи с вейвформой происходят. Дергается, пока сам музыка не буферизуется. 
Подскажите, что может быть не так?

Вот код загрузки самого плеера:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var jp_volume = 0.85;
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3:"http://ссылка на mp3"
            });
            $('.jp-progress div').width('740px');
        },
        swfPath: "http://barracudasound.com/js/audio/Jplayer.swf",
        supplied: "mp3",
        minPlaybackRate:0.1,
        size: {width:740},
        volume: jp_volume,
        verticalVolume: true,
        solution:"html,flash",
        errorAlerts:"true",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode:"window",
        oggSupport: false,
        volumechange: function (event) {
            var Vol = event.jPlayer.options.volume;
            $.cookie('jp_volume', Vol, { expires: 7, path: '/'});
        }
    });
});    
</script>
```